# Show result in MySQL in PHP error

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what is wrong. This query is returning in PHPMyAdmin normaly.
Can someone help me please?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT depoimento, nome from depoimentos WHERE avaliado = '1'");
<?PHP
                                $i = 0;
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
                                    if($i < 1){
                                        printf("<div style='display:block' id='id-$i'><p>%s<br><br><i>%s</i></p></div>", $row[0], $row[1]);
                                    }else{
                                        printf("<div style='display:none' id='id-$i'><p>%s<br><br><i>%s</i></p></div>", $row[0], $row[1]);
                                    }
                                    $i= $i+1;
                                }
                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                // store state that we can update
                                var currentVisible = 0;
                                // function to update the state and display
                                function change() {
                                    // hide the old item
                                    document.getElementById('id-'+currentVisible).style.display = 'none';
                                    // update the current index
                                    if (currentVisible < 10){
                                        currentVisible++;
                                    }else{
                                        currentVisible=0;
                                    }
                                    // show the new item
                                    document.getElementById('id-'+currentVisible).style.display = 'block';

                                    setTimeout(change, 8000);
                                }

                                // queue the first change
                                setTimeout(change, 8000);
                            </script>
```

Hello I have this code and its returnin this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/public_html/pampulhatech.com.br/empresa.php on line 91
```

Comment: why is this line `$result = mysql_query("SELECT depoimento, nome from depoimentos WHERE avaliado = '1'");` out of `<?php` ??

Answer (score 0):

your variable `$result` is out of `<?php` so that when you use `mysql_fetch_array()` it can't find the right variable.

try this on instead:

```
<?PHP
$result = mysql_query("SELECT depoimento, nome from depoimentos WHERE avaliado = '1'");

                            $i = 0;
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
                                if($i < 1){
                                    printf("<div style='display:block' id='id-$i'><p>%s<br><br><i>%s</i></p></div>", $row[0], $row[1]);
                                }else{
                                    printf("<div style='display:none' id='id-$i'><p>%s<br><br><i>%s</i></p></div>", $row[0], $row[1]);
                                }
                                $i= $i+1;
                            }
                        ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            // store state that we can update
                            var currentVisible = 0;
                            // function to update the state and display
                            function change() {
                                // hide the old item
                                document.getElementById('id-'+currentVisible).style.display = 'none';
                                // update the current index
                                if (currentVisible < 10){
                                    currentVisible++;
                                }else{
                                    currentVisible=0;
                                }
                                // show the new item
                                document.getElementById('id-'+currentVisible).style.display = 'block';

                                setTimeout(change, 8000);
                            }

                            // queue the first change
                            setTimeout(change, 8000);
                        </script>
```